# WebLoad Console takes more time when compared to IDE(recorder) to execute the script

Tags: webloadui

Why does the Script take more time when we run from WebLoad Console but when we run the same script from Webload IDE (recorder)  comparatively less.

Script is recorded to load the data to DB , when we run the script from  IDE it nearly takes 1hr but when we try to run the same script from console  for 5 thread to optimize the time taken in more than 5hrs, even for single thread its the same time consumed , please could someone provide solution what is wrong or how to optimize the timetaken from 1hr to much lesser.